# R - How to convert Date fields from 3 datasets with for loop?

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert date field of 3 datasets using for loop and got the error:

> Error in as.Date.default(mydatasets[i]$Date, "%Y-%m-%d") :    do not
>   know how to convert 'mydatasets[i]$Date' to class “Date”

Here's the code:

```
papel_BBD <-read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BBD",sep=",", header=1)
papel_HSBC <-read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=HSBC",sep=",", header=1)
papel_ITAU <-read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ITUB",sep=",", header=1)


mydatasets <- c(papel_BBD, papel_HSBC, papel_ITAU)

for (i in 1:length(mydatasets)) {
  mydatasets[i]$Date <- as.Date(mydatasets[i]$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

Console:

```
for (i in 1:length(mydatasets)) {
  mydatasets[i]$Date <- as.Date(mydatasets[i]$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

> Error in as.Date.default(mydatasets[i]$Date, "%Y-%m-%d") :    do not
>   know how to convert 'mydatasets[i]$Date' to class “Date”

I think I'm missing something in this line inside the for loop:

```
mydatasets[i]$Date <- as.Date(mydatasets[i]$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a minimal data set with your question. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) question.

Comment: I think you need the format `as.Date(mydatasets[i]$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: For that I need to know `mydatasets$Date`. The `%m/%d/%Y` part of `as.Date` depends on format of `mydatasets$Date` column.

Comment: @Narendra If you look at the url, it gives the info.

Comment: @akrun oh, didn't notice that before.

Comment: I tried your code, it is reading the 'Date' in the `%Y-%m-%d` format for me.  We need to only change the `factor` to `Date` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for(i in length(mydatasets)){
    if(is.factor(mydatasets[[i]])){
        mydatasets[[i]] <- as.Date(mydatasets[[i]])
    }
}

str(mydatasets)

## $ Date     : Date[1:3346], format: "2015-11-13" "2015-11-12" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-10" ...
## $ Open     : num [1:3346] 5.64 5.61 5.81 5.5 5.67 5.69 5.69 5.82 5.51 5.48 ...
## $ High     : num [1:3346] 5.68 5.78 5.81 5.75 5.71 5.83 5.85 5.86 5.86 5.55 ...
## $ Low      : num [1:3346] 5.51 5.59 5.63 5.41 5.53 5.61 5.65 5.61 5.51 5.38 ...
## $ Close    : num [1:3346] 5.58 5.64 5.81 5.65 5.6 5.83 5.81 5.67 5.83 5.53 ...
## $ Volume   : int [1:3346] 15207900 11032800 19484900 13652300 17659600 11074400 12065900 16797400 24521100 17566100 ...
## $ Adj.Close: num [1:3346] 5.58 5.64 5.81 5.65 5.6 ...
## $ Date     : Date[1:4111], format: "2015-11-13" "2015-11-12" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-10" ...
## $ Open     : num [1:4111] 39.1 39.8 39.9 39.5 40.3 ...
## ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` with the correct `format` (based on the urls)  for the 'Date' column.

```
lst <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern='^papel\\_.*')), transform, 
               Date=as.Date(Date))
lapply(lst, head, 2)
#$papel_BBD
#        Date Open High  Low Close   Volume Adj.Close
#1 2015-11-13 5.64 5.68 5.51  5.58 15207900      5.58
#2 2015-11-12 5.61 5.78 5.59  5.64 11032800      5.64

#$papel_HSBC
#        Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume Adj.Close
#1 2015-11-13 39.07 39.18 38.85 38.92 1922600     38.92
#2 2015-11-12 39.75 39.86 39.53 39.57 2020700     39.57

#$papel_ITAU
#        Date Open High  Low Close   Volume Adj.Close
#1 2015-11-13 7.36 7.41 7.11  7.14 15996600      7.14
#2 2015-11-12 7.36 7.51 7.30  7.36 14638300      7.36
```

It is better to keep the datasets in the `list` itself.  If we need to reflect the changes in the original dataset, we can use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)

str(papel_BBD)
#'data.frame':   3346 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ Date     : Date, format: "2015-11-13" "2015-11-12" ...
# $ Open     : num  5.64 5.61 5.81 5.5 5.67 5.69 5.69 5.82 5.51 5.48 ...
# $ High     : num  5.68 5.78 5.81 5.75 5.71 5.83 5.85 5.86 5.86 5.55 ...
# $ Low      : num  5.51 5.59 5.63 5.41 5.53 5.61 5.65 5.61 5.51 5.38 ...
# $ Close    : num  5.58 5.64 5.81 5.65 5.6 5.83 5.81 5.67 5.83 5.53 ...
# $ Volume   : int  15207900 11032800 19484900 13652300 17659600 11074400 12065900 16797400 24521100 17566100 ...
# $ Adj.Close: num  5.58 5.64 5.81 5.65 5.6 ...
```